# The minimum value is not recognize

Tags: c, max, min

The maximum value is recognize but not in minimum value ? Can you help me find the problem in this code. Or there is problem on compiler?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int e,i,sval,lval;

    printf("\nInput the length of the array:");
    scanf("%d", &e);

    int v[e];
    printf("\nInput the array element:\n");

    for(i=1; i<=e; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }
    for(i=1; i<=e; i++)
    {
        if(sval > v[i])
        {
            sval = v[i];
        }
        else
        {
            lval = v[i];
        }

    }

    printf("Smallest value : %d\n", sval);
    printf("Larger value : %d\n", lval);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a few problems with this code:

1. Arrays in C, start at index 0, so we needed to adjust in a few places.
2. The min and max values needed to be initialized appropriately.
3. There was a logic issue when determining which value was the smallest/largest during your loop.

Please see comments inline.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int e, i, min_val, max_val;
    min_val = INT_MAX;
    max_val = INT_MIN;
    // Need to initialize these to min/max values
    // We set the smallest value to the largest value because
    // presumably all other values will be lower than this. 
    // The same is true for the larger value.

    printf("\nInput the length of the array:");
    scanf("%d", &e);

    int v[e];
    printf("\nInput the array element:\n");

    // as mentioned, arrays start at 0
    for(i = 0; i < e; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < e; i++)
    {
        if (min_val > v[i]) {
            min_val = v[i];
        }
        // Need a separate condition here, not an else.
        // In your example, you had the statement:
        // "If the value I am currently looking at is smaller than
        // my currently known smallest value, assign it to the larger
        // value" <- this is a logic flaw. It becomes apparent in sets
        // such as the one shown: [9, 8, 2, 6]
        // In your example, when we reach the iteration
        // where we are looking at the 6, since that is larger
        // than the currently known smallest value of 2, we would 
        // assign the 6 to the largest value, when it should be 9.
        if (max_val < v[i]) {
            max_val = v[i];
        }
    }

    printf("Smallest value : %d\n", min_val);
    printf("Larger value : %d\n", max_val);

    return 0;
}
```

```
(venv) [ttucker@zim stackoverflow]$ gcc -o min_max min_max.c 
(venv) [ttucker@zim stackoverflow]$ ./min_max 

Input the length of the array:4

Input the array element:
9
8
2
6
Smallest value : 2
Larger value : 9
```

Comment: Just for fun, assume that I think it is not correct. Please convince me by explaining how this works and why it is supposed to fix the problem. That would also nicely help with fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a platform for offering and finding unpaid programming work.

Comment: @Yunnosch Done. I hear you on the misconceptions. I usually try to add more detail in my answers. I guess it is getting too late for stack overflowing.

Comment: To be a perfect answer, I would also suggest to use a meaningful name for the variables, `min` and `max` instead of `sval` and `lval`

Comment: Good work. My respect for taking my proposal (sometimes people just feel attacked, which is also perfectly human). Just for the outer appearance I recommend to do a global summary of the core solution in prose (i.e. outside of code). Have my upvote though, whether you do that or not. Have fun.

Answer (score 4):

#### Arrays are 0 based in C

```
int v[e];
printf("\nInput the array element:\n");

for(i=1; i<=e; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &v[i]);
}
```

and here: `i<=e` you are accessing outside of the bounds of the array, switch to

```
for(i=0; i<e; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &v[i]);
}
```

same for

```
for(i=1; i<=e; i++)
{
    if(sval > v[i])
    {
        sval = v[i];
    }
    else
    {
        lval = v[i];
    }

}
```

#### Initialize the variable `sval` and `lval` before use

```
int e,i,sval = 0,lval = 0;
```

Comment: Initializing `sval=0` would mean that we if we were given a list of `[2, 4, 5, 6]` there would never be any numbers found below 0, and so, 0 would be found as the min.

Comment: True, since this point is very well explained in your answer, I left it as is just to point the errors.

Comment: `sval`  should be set to [INT_MAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#limits.h), any value will be smaller or equal. `lval` should be set to INT_MIN, any value will be larger or equal.